# What are people using for html form generation?

Tags: html, forms, service

There is a similar question from 2009 which mentions Wufoo and FormAssembly services. Are there any other services you would recommend for generating html forms?

I simply want to generate the code for the forms (some with a lot of fields) for my php application. I don't want a hosted solution or anything such as those mentioned above. What do you use for this tedious process?

Thanks.

Comment: You should explain why you do not want to use your mentioned examples Wufoo and FormAssembly.

Comment: @chelmertz: I think the explanation is in the line: `I don't want a hosted solution or anything such as those mentioned above.`

Comment: To clarify, the services mentioned have a monthly subscription pricing model and specialize in hosting and processing your forms for you. Wufoo does allow you to download the code. I'm considering signing up, generating all my forms, and then cancelling after the first month. I thought others might be using a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found what I was looking for. Must be newly indexed because it didn't turn up in my search the first time. In case anyone else is looking for something similar:

http://www.phpform.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [`Zend_Form`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html). It generates HTML for you but you have to write quite a lot of php - with the reward of contained validation rules and decoration (container elements etc).

Or are you looking for a solution that let's you use a GUI to generate the form? In that case Wufoo seems like a good choice, I guess.